# Read XML file and write attributes into specific tags

Tags: xml, r, string, insert

I want to archive the following. I have a XML file (to be specific a osm file) with the following structure:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="osmconvert 0.8.2">
    <node id="-1" lat="47.4881774" lon="12.9061299">
        <tag k="NAMECAT" v="7355"/>
        <tag k="gml_id" v="F8191__140687"/>
        <tag k="FEAT_NAME" v="Das steinerne Meer"/>
        <tag k="OBJECTID_1" v="140687"/>
        <tag k="OBJECTID" v="1437"/>
    </node>
<way id="-1">
        <nd ref="-2"/>
        <nd ref="-3"/>
        <nd ref="-4"/>
        <nd ref="-5"/>
        <tag k="bla" v="1111"/>
        <tag k="OBJECTID" v="12345"/>
        <tag k="Short" v="old"/>
        <tag k="gml_id" v="F5371__358"/>
        <tag k="NAME" v="sdfsfd"/>
        <tag k="street" v="Blablastreet 15"/>
</way>

etc.
etc.
</osm>
```

so what i now want to do is write into the `<node>`  and `<way>` tags:

```
<node id="-1" lat="58.4881774" lon="67.9061299">
```

and

```
<way id="-1" version="1">
```

I want to write two strings (`timestamp="1970-01-01T00:00:01Z" version="1"`) into this tags (which are probably about some hundred) so that the result looks like this:

```
<node id="-1" lat="58.4881774" lon="67.9061299" changeset="1" timestamp="1970-01-01T00:00:01Z" version="1" >
```

and

```
<way id="-1" version="1" changeset="1" timestamp="1970-01-01T00:00:01Z" version="1">
```

the position is not important its just important that it is written between the `<way...>` and `<node...>`

Of course i want to save the changes in the end and in the best of cases into the same xml file. I already tried to archive something like that using the `XML package` but failed.  The `readLines` command looked promising if i cloud write something like insert my string after every `<way id"-1"` or `<node id"-1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
library(XML)

doc <- xmlParse('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="osmconvert 0.8.2">
    <node id="-1" lat="47.4881774" lon="12.9061299">
        <tag k="NAMECAT" v="7355"/>
        <tag k="gml_id" v="F8191__140687"/>
        <tag k="FEAT_NAME" v="Das steinerne Meer"/>
        <tag k="OBJECTID_1" v="140687"/>
        <tag k="OBJECTID" v="1437"/>
    </node>
<way id="-1">
        <nd ref="-2"/>
        <nd ref="-3"/>
        <nd ref="-4"/>
        <nd ref="-5"/>
        <tag k="bla" v="1111"/>
        <tag k="OBJECTID" v="12345"/>
        <tag k="Short" v="old"/>
        <tag k="gml_id" v="F5371__358"/>
        <tag k="NAME" v="sdfsfd"/>
        <tag k="street" v="Blablastreet 15"/>
</way></osm>')

invisible(xpathApply(doc, "//node", function(x) xmlAttrs(x) <- c(timestamp="1970-01-01T00:00:01Z", version="1")))
invisible(xpathApply(doc, "//way", function(x) xmlAttrs(x) <- c(timestamp="1970-01-01T00:00:01Z", version="1")))

cat(saveXML(doc))
```

This is the output from the `cat`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="osmconvert 0.8.2">
  <node id="-1" lat="47.4881774" lon="12.9061299" timestamp="1970-01-01T00:00:01Z" version="1">
    <tag k="NAMECAT" v="7355"/>
    <tag k="gml_id" v="F8191__140687"/>
    <tag k="FEAT_NAME" v="Das steinerne Meer"/>
    <tag k="OBJECTID_1" v="140687"/>
    <tag k="OBJECTID" v="1437"/>
  </node>
  <way id="-1" timestamp="1970-01-01T00:00:01Z" version="1">
    <nd ref="-2"/>
    <nd ref="-3"/>
    <nd ref="-4"/>
    <nd ref="-5"/>
    <tag k="bla" v="1111"/>
    <tag k="OBJECTID" v="12345"/>
    <tag k="Short" v="old"/>
    <tag k="gml_id" v="F5371__358"/>
    <tag k="NAME" v="sdfsfd"/>
    <tag k="street" v="Blablastreet 15"/>
  </way>
</osm>
```

and you can use `saveXML` to write it to a file.

Comment: Exactly like that.Then i was pretty much on the right way but well i probably would not have figured out how to write into the XML file. The documentation is pretty complicated for the `XML package`. Anyway thank you! Now i have to get the logic behind that code.